# Is an infinite direct sum of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules quasi-coherent on a complex manifold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, quasi-coherent-modules, ringed-spaces

On any ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ we can define quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules: A sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent if  for every point $x\in X$ there exists an open neighborhood $x\in U\subset X$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of a map

$$
\bigoplus_{j\in J}\mathcal{O}_U \to \bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathcal{O}_U.
$$
See [Stack Project Section 17.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BD).

We know that in general an infinite direct sum of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules is not necessarily quasi-coherent. See [Stack Project Example 17.10.9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BL). On the other hand, if $X$ is a scheme, then any direct sum of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules is still quasi-coherent. See [Stack Project Section 26.24](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LA).

We can consider quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules over ringed spaces which are not schemes. For example, $X$ is a complex manifold and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions.

> > My question is: for a complex manifold $X$ with $\mathcal{O}_X$  the sheaf of holomorphic functions, is an infinite direct sum of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules still quasi-coherent?

Comment: That is not true.  Gabber constructs a (nonzero) quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}(p,q)$ on the open unit disk $X$ in the complex plane that has vanishing global sections on every open disk containing both $p$ and $q$.  Now let $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ be sequences of points in the punctured unit disk that limit to zero.  The direct sum of the sheaves $\mathcal{F}(p_n,q_n)$ is globally generated on no open disk containing zero.

Comment: Just to clarify, Gabber constructs a quasi-coherent sheaf that is isomorphic to a direct sum of countably many copies of the structure sheaf on either $X\setminus \{p\}$ or $X\setminus\{q\}$.